# javascript getDate getMonth returns wrong month

Tags: javascript, date

I know there have been other posts about this but I can't see to figure out what I am doing wrong here. Below is my code:

```
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth();
System.log(d);
System.log(month);
```

My output looks like this:

```
[2015-04-01 09:24:53.012] [I] Wed Apr 01 2015 09:24:53 GMT-0400 (EDT)
[2015-04-01 09:24:53.012] [I] 3
```

Shouldn't the bottom output be a 4?

Thanks in advance

Comment: not if you are starting to count at 0

Comment: Read the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth It explains why

Comment: Month counts, in javascripts, starts from 0 instead of 1. There are about one thousand topics about that on SO anyway! ;)

Comment: Sneaky JS getMonth() strikes again...

Answer (score 6):

it is an array.
month starts with 0,
so you should plus 1 by yourself.

you can take a look at this :)

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown unless the specific linked resource contains a factual error, I don't see any reason for changing a link. Just because W3schools contains mistakes in other places?

Comment: @doldt all right, keep using w3schools for you guys own risk...

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as an array, the indices start at 0. January is 0, March is 1, etc.

Comment: it's too late i know but isn't March 2 ?